# How to get the selected value of Html.DropDownListFor in aspx engine?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

In Html (which I did not use) it's

```
<select>
<option value="B">Bubblegum</option>
</select>
```

In (from controller) Aspx it's

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViewMethod()
{
//Populate DropDownList
Treats = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
Treats.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Bubblegum", "B"));
ViewData["treats"] = new SelectList(Treats, "Value", "Key", SelectedTreat);
return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeneratedContent(SomeModel model)
{
List<HalloweenTreats> ChewingGums = StoredProc(model.SelectedTreat);
return PartialView(ChewingGums);
}
```

then in the View:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("ViewMethod", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DisplayValues" })) { %>

<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTreat, ViewData["treats"] as SelectList)%>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'generate' />
<div id="DisplayValues"></div>
<% } %>
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Generate", "RequestReportSummary", "Report", new { model = Model }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "GeneratedReport" })%>
```

How to get the selected value "B" of Html.DropDownListFor in aspx engine for me to send it as a string in the database?

Comment: Do you mean getting by javascript?

Comment: no, not using any of javascript

Comment: Just use a form with a submit button

Comment: I edited the question, the problem is that the stored procedure receives an empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller action you are posting to could take your model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewMethod(SomeModel model)
{
    // model.SelectedTreat will contain the selected value here
}
```

Comment: If you select a value in the view, the `SelectedTreat` string property should be populated with this selected value. It's a `string` property in your model, right? Because if it is some complex object you cannot possibly expect the default model binder to be able to instantiate this complex object from a string value which is what is being sent when you submit the form. It's up to you to use this string value to fetch the corresponding model in your action.

Comment: Yes it's a string property.  The generated content from the method which is a partial view does not appear.

Comment: Where is it supposed to appear? Is the method invoked at all? Did you include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That script would open a new tab, I wanted the partial view to appear below the first view. The first view filters the content that will appear.

Comment: Alright, but that's quite a lot of things and the amount of code you have shown is very narrow for us to be able to help you. You probably did something wrong, but since you haven't shown your code I can't possibly know what.

Comment: Your `ViewMethod` action doesn't seem to return anything. It is completely unclear where and how the `GeneratedContent` action is invoked. It is unclear how your models look like. It is unclear to what model are your views strongly typed. So much missing information. If you are going to post some code, please post real code allowing us to reproduce the problem you are encountering.

Comment: I forgot to include the line where I am calling the partial view